# PyQt5, setPixmap not working with image links

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to get an image from a link and have it display on a label but whenever I try to set the pixmap it breaks, with the application crashing. Everything up till that point works fine so it's really strange this is happening. This is my code, I've tried every solution I can think of and I'm at my wits end with this not working, Please help.

```
image = 'https://preview.redd.it/2il4zqu6ke451.jpg?auto=webp&s=e88781e6529a093b7c2d35d9deac3e415f149b1b'
image = Image.open(requests.get(image, stream=True).raw)
image = ImageQt(image)
image = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
self.ui.title1.setPixmap(image)
```

tried different image types and different links with them all not working. I have imported and installed all libraries despite what the code shows, its part of a bigger program.

Comment: Try to run the code in a terminal or prompt and look for errors the IDE may not be able to show. Also, consider that you shouldn't try to use possibly blocking (or potentially failing) calls in the main UI thread, and you should use threading for that, possibly through QThread and proper signals (UI elements are not thread safe). Also, Qt provides the QNetworkAccessManager API, which is natively asynchronous.

Comment: Ill try with networkaccessmanager, is it as simple is using get with that or is there more to it?

Comment: PIL is the most likely culprit here, which is actually redundant in the specific example you gave. The code can be simplified to a one-liner: `pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage( QImage.fromData(requests.get(url, stream=True).content))`. The issue with your code is that you are repeatedly overwriting a single variable, which will sometimes result in PIL dropping the reference to the underlying image data. If Qt tries to read that data after its been deleted, you will obviously get a crash (i.e. a memory access violation).